# Load eslint plugin rules by default

Tags: javascript, eslint

I have created a eslint plugin (i.e. eslint-plugin-components) with two rules: `no-wait` and `no-huge-timeout`. If I add these two rules to `.eslintrc` like this, eslint works properly:

```
{
  "extends": "airbnb-base",
  "plugins": ["components"],
  "rules": {
    "components/no-wait": 2,
    "components/no-huge-timeouts": 2
  }
}
```

What I've been trying to do is to load them at my plugin's index, like this:

```
'use strict';

var requireIndex = require('requireindex');

module.exports.rules = requireIndex(__dirname + '/lib/rules');

module.exports.configs = {
  rules: {
    'components/no-wait': 2,
    'components/no-huge-timeouts': 2
  }
};
```

But this way eslint does not load them. My question would be if it's posible to do what I'm trying to do and how could I do that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [documentation](http://eslint.org/docs/developer-guide/working-with-plugins#configs-in-plugins), you have to include a named configuration in `configs`:

```
module.exports.configs = {
  some_name: {
    rules: {
      'components/no-wait': 2,
      'components/no-huge-timeouts': 2
    }
  }
};
```

And you would [reference that named configuration](http://eslint.org/docs/user-guide/configuring#using-the-configuration-from-a-plugin) in your `.eslintrc`:

```
{
  "plugins": ["components"],
  "extends": [
    "airbnb-base",
    "plugin:components/some_name"
  ]
}
```